# Use older version of Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, version, switch-statement

I have Rake version 0.9.1 but I need to use 0.8.7 for a project, and I'm fairly certain I have both version installed but it always uses 0.9.1 by default. Is there a way to specify which version of Rake to use?

I'm trying to run this: rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
and I get this error:
You have already activated rake 0.9.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Consider using bundle exec.

Comment: Well, the answer was in your question: **Consider using bundle exec** ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can specify the version of Rake to use, in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

Though the "error" message you are getting says it all... you need to run:

```
bundle exec rake ...
```

... in order to use the right rake to run your rake tasks.

More info on `bundle exec`: http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Answer (score 26):

gem search (or list) rake, should tell you which versions are installed.

You can invoke rake with a specific version number bracketed with
underscores.

`$rake _0.7.3_`

This is a standard feature of gem packaged binaries.

Answer (score 8):

Try executing `gem uninstall rake` then just pick the version you want to uninstall.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you are using **rake** from the system. (latest version by default)
The solution is use follow command:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Also, you can create alias. Because this command is too big and difficult to write.

```
echo "alias be='bundle exec'" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you can use follow short command:

```
be rake db:migrate
```