# rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'sandbox'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sandbox, spree

I'm trying to add the sandbox to my rails spree application and have run into this error 
(using windows 8/powershell with Rails 4.1.6). I'm going by this manual: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/411

This link [Use older version of Rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243304/use-older-version-of-rake)
seems to have a similar issue but I am not sure how to take the necessary steps to achieve it.

When I try:

```
C:\Ruby193\openUpShop> bundle exec rake sandbox
```

I get:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'sandbox'
```

I'm am new to rails and am still not sure how everything works so a throughout explanation
with step by step instructions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a file sandbox.rb

```
# use example: rake task:sub_task -- --sandbox

if ARGV.any? {|arg| arg == '--sandbox' }
  puts "** << USING SANDBOX!! >> **"

  # beginning
  $sandbox = -> do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.begin_transaction
  end

  # end
  at_exit do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.rollback_transaction
  end
end
```

then only you need add at the beginning of your task.rake file

```
require_relative 'path_to_your/sandbox.rb'
```

..and add at the beggining of your task code

```
desc "description task"
task example_task: :environment do
    $sandbox.call if $sandbox.present?
...
```